# Update look up field

Tags: trigger

I have a look up field to Account on opportunity object, how do I update the look up field value to opportunity name when ever opportunity name is changed. I'm using before insert/update Trigger to achieve this, but I'm unable to figure out on how to assign. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: To clarify:  You would like to update the name of the Account (the lookup field on the opportunity) to match the name of the Opportunity?

Comment: Yes Sir, that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is stated, there is nothing you need to do.

A lookup to an opportunity is a Foreign Key that links to the Opportunity. In the UI is displays the name of the opportunity. Thus, if you change the name of the opportunity, the modified name in the account for the Lookup Field will also reflect this changed.

Comment: Eric as mentioned in the above comment, I'd like to update the name of the Account (the lookup field on the opportunity) to match the name of the Opportunity